# My RichTextBox's cut/copy/paste doesn't cut, copy, or paste

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox, copy-paste

Here's my code:

```
void CutAction(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox2.Cut();
}

void CopyAction(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Rtf, richTextBox2.SelectedRtf);
    Clipboard.Clear();
}

void PasteAction(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Clipboard.ContainsText(TextDataFormat.Rtf))
    {
        richTextBox2.SelectedRtf
            = Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Rtf).ToString();
    }
}

private void richTextBox2_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
    {   //click event
        //MessageBox.Show("you got it!");
        ContextMenu contextMenu = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu();
        MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem("Cut");
        menuItem.Click += new EventHandler(CutAction);
        contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(menuItem);
        menuItem = new MenuItem("Copy");
        menuItem.Click += new EventHandler(CopyAction);
        contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(menuItem);
        menuItem = new MenuItem("Paste");
        menuItem.Click += new EventHandler(PasteAction);
        contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(menuItem);

        richTextBox2.ContextMenu = contextMenu;
    }
}
```

I have 2 problems:

- After marking the text in `richTextbox2` I need to simulate a right click on the mouse to see the cut paste copy menu.
- When I click on Copy I can't afterwards paste it anywhere because there is nothing to paste. I didn't test yet the cut and paste options but after doing copy it's not working.

Comment: When `CopyAction` is called, you set the clipboard and then clear it. I'm sure that's not what you meant.

Comment: @ColeJohnson yes, overlooked it.

Comment: @ColeJohnson what does "it's being at the top of the code" have to do with it? If you clear the clipboard the data is gone when the Copy menu item is clicked then you have nothing to paste.

Comment: @N4TKD it was a reply to King King who didn't notice the `CopyAction` method, so I said it was at the top of the code block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `Clipboard.Clear();`

```
void CopyAction(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Rtf, richTextBox2.SelectedRtf);            
}
```

You can also use the `Copy()` method of a `RichTextBox`:

```
void CopyAction(object sender, EventArgs e) {
 richTextBox2.Copy();
}
```

For paste:

```
void PasteAction(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   if (Clipboard.ContainsText(TextDataFormat.Rtf)) {
      SendKeys.Send("^v");
   } 
}
```

Comment: Beat me too it... -_-

Comment: Ok its working now but the paste is working only on richTextBox2 control. If i want the paste to work on any other windows like in cgrome or in a text file i have or anywhere else ?

Comment: @DoronMuzar that's a little complicated, theoretically you have to detect the focused window and send some `WM_PASTE` message to that window.

Comment: @DoronMuzar there is another easier option for you, see the update.

Answer (score 2):

```
private void btnCopy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox1.SelectAll();
    richTextBox1.Copy();
}

private void btnPaste_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox2.Paste();
}

private void btnCut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox1.SelectAll();
    richTextBox1.Cut();
}
```

**Note**:The windows forms has built in methods to copy the text from richTextBox to Clipboard.
like Copy, Paste, Cut (you have to select the text first which you want to copy or cut. **Here in my example i had given select all text**).

Here in this example basically it will copy the content to the clipboard, still there are overloading methods please see the definitions of the methods.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `toolstripbar`, add 3 `toolstripbuttons`. This is the code for copy, cut and paste

```
private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SendKeys.Send("^x");
}

private void toolStripButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SendKeys.Send("^v");
}

private void toolStripButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SendKeys.Send("^c");
}
```

The code works directly with the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answer mr Doron Muzar

```
  private void richTextBox2_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   {
     if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
       {   //click event
           //MessageBox.Show("you got it!");
           ContextMenu contextMenu = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu();
           MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem("Cut");
           menuItem.Click += new EventHandler(CutAction);
           contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(menuItem);
           menuItem = new MenuItem("Copy");
           menuItem.Click += new EventHandler(CopyAction);
           contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(menuItem);
           menuItem = new MenuItem("Paste");
           menuItem.Click += new EventHandler(PasteAction);
           contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(menuItem);

           richTextBox2.ContextMenu = contextMenu;
}
```

}

```
    void CutAction(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Cut();
    }

    void CopyAction(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Copy();

    }

    void PasteAction(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {`
        richTextBox1.Paste();
    }
```